# Show wait cursor on touch screen wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have a WPF application that runs almost exclusively on tablets.  There are some operations that can have a short but noticeable delay on WIFI. My solution was to use the wait cursor since a full loading screen is not necessary.  It works great on a desktop but on a tablet the cursor is not visible unless the user is touching the screen.  If there is not a fix I am open to alternatives.

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
//Do stuff
this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
```

Comment: You can also show a loading circle gif.

Comment: I read something about that but it looked like I was going to need to use winforms.  Is that correct?

Comment: You only need to load a `.gif` to your project and play it when you start loading. It would require you to start this asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try like this:

1.Prepare:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern int SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

private void UpdateCursor()
{
    var position = PointToScreen(new Point(ActualWidth / 2, ActualHeight / 2));
    SetCursorPos((int)position.X + 1, (int)position.Y + 1);
}
```

2.Invoke:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
UpdateCursor();
//Do stuff
this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
UpdateCursor();
```